# Is there any NLP framework/ algorithm which is able to derive relationships between different entities?

Tags: nlp

Is there any NLP framework/ algorithm which is able to derive relationships between different entities?

- Dogs bark
- For example, if the system can identify and understand a phrase, 'Dogs were barking loudly' and can relate to another phrase, 'Usually dogs bark loud, when they sense danger'. And from this piece of information, the system can imply/ derive: 'Dogs had sensed danger' - derived sentence.

Can BERT help in identifying and implying?

Answer (score 0):

What you describe touches on several tasks in NLP:

- [semantic role labeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_role_labeling)
- [relationship extraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relationship_extraction)
- paraphrase detection and [textual entaiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Textual_entailment)

I might not be aware of the recent developments on these tasks, but as far as I know this is a very complex problem for which so far there is no satisfactory solution.